# Not getting desired output by adding character before and after each item in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to take multiple input from a user and store it in a variable. After storing I want to add character starting and ending of each word, but I am failing to get desired output in python 3.X

**My code is as follows:-**

```
string_value=[str(i) for i in raw_input("Enter space separated inputs: ").split()]
aces = ["\'" + string_value + "\'" for string_value in string_value]
print (aces)
```

**Output:-**

```
Enter space separated inputs: John Sunil Kathylene Bob

["' John ' ", " ' Sunil ' ", " ' Kathylene ' ", " ' Bob' "]
```

**Desired Output :-**

```
\'John\',\'Sunil\',\' Kathylene\',\' Bob\'
```

Comment: You need to esace '\' with another '\'. Try this `aces = ["\\'" + string_value + "\\'" for string_value in string_value]`

Comment: Baxkslash is a special character in Python. Use two backslashes in a row to mean a literal backslash. So '\\' + 'word' -> '\word'

Comment: The list comprehension in the first line is not accomplishing anything - the result of `.split()` is a list of strings already.

Comment: also `for string_value in string_value` is trying to give yourself a headache. Be a bit more creative with the naming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some advise:

- Read PEP8.
- Type-casting of `str` to `str` is redundant.

Code:

```
words = input("Enter space separated inputs: ").split()
prefix_and_suffix = "\\'"
formatted_words = ','.join('{0}{1}{0}'.format(
    prefix_and_suffix, word) for word in words)
print (formatted_words)
```

Comment: you can number the placeholders to avoid repeating stuff. In this case for example you could do: `'{0}{1}{0}'.format(
    prefix_and_suffix, word)`

Comment: also `raw_input` does not work in Python 3. use `input` instead.

Comment: He has tagged Python3 though and mentions it in his question as well. You can only answer the question he **did ask**, not the one you **assume he wanted to ask**.

Comment: Thanks that what i want